# Store value in database

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, tomcat6

I've started to work with a web application using Tomcat, Netbeans 7 and MySQL. I have added a drop down list to the JSP with 4 options which come from a table named `department` of a database named `studentdatabase`. This table has 2 columns `id` and `name`.

I have created a insert form in the JSP where I have to select a name from the drop down list and save it to a table named `studentinfo` of that database. This table has 3 columns `name`, `departmentid` and `email`.

For showing the drop down list I use the following code:

```
<select name="id">
  <c:forEach var="subject" items="${subjects.rows}">
    <option value="${subject.id}">${subject.name}</option>
  </c:forEach>
</select>
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: why is java tagged in this question?

Comment: @James: because OP apparently needs the answer in Java (Servlet, JDBC, etc). However, without a concrete question no one can give an answer. So we have to wait for the OP to edit and include the concrete question along with some concrete Java code he's having problems with. Please note that JSP is a Java based view technology which normally submits to a Java servlet class.

Comment: @BalusC - thanks for that detailed informative response.

Comment: My question is :how can i insert into database through a drop down list of a jsp.the options of that drop down list comes from database.

Comment: and i m sry if i did any mistake.actually i m quite new to java,jsp etc

Comment: By the way, for an entirely different way to use a drop-down list (pop-up menu) to enter a row in a database in a web app built with Java, see [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52340226/642706) to this other Question, using the [*Vaadin*](http://www.Vaadin.com/) framework.