# Output the data from the database to the user in the form on Java

Tags: java, date, web-applications, request

I am recently start learning Java. 
I need to write a web-application in Java, where the user can select the product necessary for him from the form on the home html-page from the drop-down list. The list of products is stored in a table in the database (using MySQL). Then the selected product should be written in the "order history" table. 
How to output the database from the database to the drop-down list? 
How to realize the choice of the necessary product for user? 
How can I start? Have anyone got a small example?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. I’m afraid that your question is too broad for here. If you look around, you’ll noticed that the well-received questions are nearly always a lot narrower. You should also study [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) more closely, and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) PS Why the date tag?

Comment: Try your Question on a discussion/forums site such as http://www.CodeRanch.com/. Not appropriate to Stack Overflow. And search the sister site, *Software Recommendations Stack Exchange*, for advice on web app frameworks such as [*Vaadin*](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).

Answer (score 0):

## Vaadin

Here is a complete working example using Java with the [Vaadin](http://www.Vaadin.com/) Framework version 8.5.2 to create a web app where an database run by [H2 Database Engine](http://h2database.com/html/main.html) tracks a list of products (10 planets of the solar system). A `NativeSelect` widget in Vaadin is populated from a `List` of `Product` objects loaded from a `product_` table in that database. Each time the user clicks the `Order` button, an order is recorded as a row in the `order_` table.

Here is a simple ERD diagram of the two tables in the database.

[image: Entity-relationship diagram of Product table and Order table]

The user first selects a planet product from the drop-down list, then clicks the “Order” button.

Below this data-entry area you see pair of `Grid` widgets as a back-door peek into the database. On the left is the list of products, which does not change. On the right is a list of all orders, which updates every time the user places an order with that “Order” button.

Note that the database is in-memory, not persistent, as this is just a little demo. So every time you launch the app, the database is rebuilt from scratch. The `order_` table starts out empty each run.

Lastly, this is by no means production-ready code, just an example to show possibilities. Just now while shooting that screenshot I found a bug related to choosing no product at all. *C’est la vie.*

[image]

For more info, see these sections of the *Vaadin* manual:

- [*Button*](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/components/components-button.html) – Overview of the button widget.
- [*NativeSelect*](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/components/components-nativeselect.html) — Quick demo of this drop-down list widget
- [*Selection Components*](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/components/components-selection.html#components.selection) — Discussion of how widgets such as `NativeSelect` work in Vaadin
- [*Grid*](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/components/components-grid.html) — How to use this powerful data-grid widget.

### Main app class

Basically boilerplate, to make Vaadin run. What matters is the pair of lines in the middle, for `ProductPickerLayout`.

```
package com.basilbourque.example;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;

import com.vaadin.annotations.Theme;
import com.vaadin.annotations.VaadinServletConfiguration;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinRequest;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet;
import com.vaadin.ui.*;

/**
 * This UI is the application entry point. A UI may either represent a browser window
 * (or tab) or some part of an HTML page where a Vaadin application is embedded.
 * <p>
 * The UI is initialized using {@link #init(VaadinRequest)}. This method is intended to be
 * overridden to add component to the user interface and initialize non-component functionality.
 */
@Theme ( "mytheme" )
public class MyUI extends UI {

    @Override
    protected void init ( VaadinRequest vaadinRequest ) {
        final Layout layout = new ProductPickerLayout();
        this.setContent( layout );
    }

    @WebServlet ( urlPatterns = "/*", name = "MyUIServlet", asyncSupported = true )
    @VaadinServletConfiguration ( ui = MyUI.class, productionMode = false )
    public static class MyUIServlet extends VaadinServlet {
    }
}
```

### Servlet context listener

Reacts to web app launching and exiting.

```
package com.basilbourque.example;

import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebListener;
import java.time.Instant;

@WebListener
public class MyServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener {
    MyDatabaseService databaseService;

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized ( ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent ) {
        System.out.println( "TRACE - contextInitialized " + Instant.now() );

        // Database.
        MyDatabaseService db = new MyDatabaseService();
        db.establishDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed ( ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent ) {
        // This method intentionally left blank.
    }
}
```

### Database service class

Defines and preloads the database. Provides inserts and queries, to move data in and out of database.

```
package com.basilbourque.example;

import java.sql.*;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class MyDatabaseService {
    // ---------|  Members  |------------------------------------
    static final private String driverName = "org.h2.Driver";
    static final private String catalogName = "ProdPop";
    static final private String jdbcPath = "jdbc:h2:mem:" + MyDatabaseService.catalogName + ";DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1";  // "jdbc:h2:mem:autogrid";  // Set delay to keep in-memory database even after last connection closed.
    static final private String productTableName = "product_";
    static final private String orderTableName = "order_";

    public void establishDatabase () {
        // Verify JDBC driver.
        try {
            Class.forName( MyDatabaseService.driverName );
        } catch ( ClassNotFoundException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Connect, and create database.
        try ( Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection( MyDatabaseService.jdbcPath ) ;
        ) {
            String sql = null;

            // Create product_ table.
            // Columns: pkey_  name_
            try ( Statement stmt = conn.createStatement() ; ) {
                sql = "CREATE TABLE " + productTableName + " ( \n" +
                      " pkey_ IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY , \n" +
                      " name_ VARCHAR ( 80 ) NOT NULL \n" +
                      ") ; \n";
                System.out.println( "TRACE - SQL:\n" + sql );
                stmt.execute( sql );
            }
            System.out.println( "TRACE - Created table product_." );

            // Create order_ table.
            // Columns: pkey_  fkey_product_  when_ordered_
            try ( Statement stmt = conn.createStatement() ; ) {
                sql = "CREATE TABLE " + orderTableName + " ( \n" +
                      "  pkey_ IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY  , \n" +
                      "  fkey_product_ LONG NOT NULL , \n" +
                      "  when_ordered_  TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  \n" +
                      ") ; \n" +
                      "ALTER TABLE " + orderTableName + " ADD FOREIGN KEY ( fkey_product_ ) REFERENCES product_ ( pkey_ ) ; \n "
                ;
                System.out.println( "TRACE - SQL:\n" + sql );
                stmt.execute( sql );
            }

            // List tables
            DatabaseMetaData md = conn.getMetaData();
            try ( ResultSet rs = md.getTables( null , null , null , null ) ) {
                while ( rs.next() ) {
                    System.out.println( rs.getString( 3 ) );
                }
            }

            // List columns of `product_` table.
            try ( ResultSet rs = md.getColumns( null , null , productTableName.toUpperCase( Locale.US ) , null ) ) {
                System.out.println( "Columns of table: " + productTableName );
                while ( rs.next() ) {
                    System.out.println( rs.getString( 4 ) + " | " + rs.getString( 5 ) + " | " + rs.getString( 6 ) ); // COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE , TYPE_NAME.
                }
            }

            // List columns of `order_` table.
            try ( ResultSet rs = md.getColumns( null , null , orderTableName.toUpperCase( Locale.US ) , null ) ) {
                System.out.println( "Columns of table: " + orderTableName );
                while ( rs.next() ) {
                    System.out.println( rs.getString( 4 ) + " | " + rs.getString( 5 ) + " | " + rs.getString( 6 ) ); // COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE , TYPE_NAME.
                }
            }

            // Add rows
            sql = "INSERT INTO product_ ( name_ ) \n" +
                  "VALUES ( ? ) " +
                  "; ";

            List< String > planets = List.of( "Mercury" , "Venus" , "Earth" , "Mars" , "Ceres" , "Jupiter" , "Saturn" , "Uranus" , "Neptune" , "Pluto" );
            try ( PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement( sql ) ; ) {
                for ( String planet : planets ) {
                    ps.setString( 1 , planet );
                    ps.executeUpdate();
                }
            }

            System.out.println( "TRACE - Dumping tables in their initial state. " + Instant.now() );
            this.dumpTableToConsole( MyDatabaseService.productTableName );
            this.dumpTableToConsole( MyDatabaseService.orderTableName );
        } catch ( SQLException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void dumpTableToConsole ( String tableName ) {

        try ( Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection( MyDatabaseService.jdbcPath ) ;
        ) {
            System.out.println( "TRACE - « " + tableName + " » table dump to console at " + Instant.now() );
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName + " ;";
            try ( Statement stmt = conn.createStatement() ;
                  ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( sql ) ; ) {
                ResultSetMetaData meta = rs.getMetaData();
                int colCount = meta.getColumnCount();
                int rowCount = 0;
                while ( rs.next() ) {
                    rowCount++;
                    System.out.print( "Row # " + rowCount + ": " );
                    for ( int col = 1 ; col <= colCount ; col++ ) {
                        System.out.print( meta.getColumnLabel( col ) + "=" );
                        Object o = rs.getObject( col );
                        if ( null != o ) {
                            System.out.print( o.toString() + " " );
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println( "" ); // Newline.
                }
                System.out.println( "« fin de " + tableName + " »" );
            }
        } catch ( SQLException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public List< Product > fetchAllProducts () {
        System.out.println( "TRACE MyDatabaseService::fetchAllOrders at " + Instant.now() );

        List< Product > products = new ArrayList<>();

        // Query. Loop ResultSet, instantiating object, and collecting.
        try ( Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection( MyDatabaseService.jdbcPath ) ;
        ) {
            System.out.println( "TRACE - fetchAllProducts at " + Instant.now() );
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + productTableName + " ;";
            try (
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement() ;
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( sql ) ;
            ) {
                int rowCount = 0;
                while ( rs.next() ) {
                    Long pkey = rs.getLong( "pkey_" );
                    String name = rs.getString( "name_" );
                    // Make object from column values.
                    Product p = new Product( pkey , name );
                    products.add( p ); // Collect each `Order` object retrieved from database.
                }
            }
        } catch ( SQLException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return products;
    }

    public List< Order > fetchAllOrders () {
        System.out.println( "TRACE MyDatabaseService::fetchAllOrders at " + Instant.now() );

        List< Order > orders = new ArrayList<>();

        // Query. Loop ResultSet, instantiating object, and collecting.
        try ( Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection( MyDatabaseService.jdbcPath ) ;
        ) {
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + orderTableName + " \n ORDER BY pkey_ DESC \n ;";
            try (
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement() ;
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( sql ) ;
            ) {
                int rowCount = 0;
                while ( rs.next() ) {
                    Long pkey = rs.getLong( "pkey_" );
                    Long fkey_product = rs.getLong( "fkey_product_" );
                    Instant when_ordered = rs.getObject( "when_ordered_" , Instant.class );
                    // Make object from column values.
                    Order o = new Order( pkey , fkey_product , when_ordered );
                    orders.add( o ); // Collect each `Order` object retrieved from database.
                }
            }
        } catch ( SQLException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return orders;
    }

    public void insertOrder ( Long fkeyProduct ) {
        System.out.println( "TRACE - MyDatabaseService::insertOrder at " + Instant.now() );
        try ( Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection( MyDatabaseService.jdbcPath ) ;
        ) {
            String sql = "INSERT INTO " + orderTableName + "( fkey_product_ )\n" + " VALUES ( ? ) ;\n";
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement( sql );
            ps.setLong( 1 , fkeyProduct );
            ps.executeUpdate();
        } catch ( SQLException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

### Content layout

Displays our widgets: the [`NativeSelect`](https://vaadin.com/api/framework/8.5.2/com/vaadin/ui/NativeSelect.html) drop-down list of products, order button, and pair of [`Grid`](https://vaadin.com/api/framework/8.5.2/com/vaadin/ui/Grid.html) data-grids. Serves as the view and the controller, for interacting with our user.

```
package com.basilbourque.example;

import com.vaadin.data.HasValue;
import com.vaadin.data.HasValue.ValueChangeEvent;
import com.vaadin.ui.*;

import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.List;

public class ProductPickerLayout extends VerticalLayout {
    Label prodPopLabel;
    NativeSelect< Product > productSelect;
    Button orderButton;

    Grid< Product > productsGrid;
    Grid< Order > ordersGrid;

    // Constructor
    public ProductPickerLayout () {
        this.widgetsMake();
        this.widgetsArrange();
    }

    private void widgetsMake () {

        // Create the selection component
        this.prodPopLabel = new Label( "Products: " );
        this.productSelect = new NativeSelect<>();
        // Add some items
        List< Product > products = new MyDatabaseService().fetchAllProducts();
        this.productSelect.setItems( products );
        this.productSelect.setItemCaptionGenerator( Product :: getName );
        // Show 5 items and a scrollbar if there are more
//        select.setRows( 3 );

        productSelect.addValueChangeListener( new HasValue.ValueChangeListener< Product >() {
            @Override
            public void valueChange ( ValueChangeEvent< Product > valueChangeEvent ) {
                Product p = valueChangeEvent.getValue();
                orderButton.setEnabled( null != p );
                Notification.show( "Selected: " + p.name );
            }
        } );

        this.orderButton = new Button( "Order" );
        this.orderButton.setEnabled( this.productSelect.getValue() != null );
        this.orderButton.addClickListener( ( Button.ClickEvent e ) -> {
            this.placeOrder();
            this.ordersGrid.setItems( new MyDatabaseService().fetchAllOrders() );
        } );

        MyDatabaseService db = new MyDatabaseService();

        this.productsGrid = new Grid<>( Product.class );
        this.productsGrid.setItems( products );
        this.productsGrid.setCaption( "Products" );

        this.ordersGrid = new Grid<>( Order.class );
        List< Order > orders = db.fetchAllOrders();
        this.ordersGrid.setItems( orders );
        this.ordersGrid.setCaption( "Orders" );
    }

    private void widgetsArrange () {
        HorizontalLayout orderBar = new HorizontalLayout();
        orderBar.setSpacing( true );
        orderBar.addComponents( this.prodPopLabel , this.productSelect , this.orderButton );
        orderBar.setComponentAlignment( this.prodPopLabel , Alignment.MIDDLE_CENTER );
        orderBar.setComponentAlignment( this.productSelect , Alignment.MIDDLE_CENTER );
        orderBar.setComponentAlignment( this.orderButton , Alignment.MIDDLE_CENTER );

        HorizontalLayout gridsBar = new HorizontalLayout();
        gridsBar.setSpacing( true );
        gridsBar.addComponents( this.productsGrid , this.ordersGrid );

        this.addComponents( orderBar , gridsBar );
        this.setExpandRatio( gridsBar , 1.0F );
    }

    private void placeOrder () {
        // Get pkey of the currently selected product.

        Product p = this.productSelect.getValue();
        if ( null == p ) {
            throw new IllegalStateException( "The `productSelect` NativeSelect does not have a current value." );
        }
        Long fkeyProduct = p.pkey;

        // Insert row into table.
        new MyDatabaseService().insertOrder( fkeyProduct );

        this.updateOrdersGrid();
    }

    private void updateOrdersGrid () {
    }
}
```

### Model classes – `Product` & `Order`

The getter/setter accessor methods are automatically detected and used by Vaadin to show data in the `Grid` data-grid widgets. Of course, you could instead do manual configuration.

Our `Product` class.

```
package com.basilbourque.example;

public class Product {
    Long pkey;
    String name;

    public Product ( Long pkey , String name ) {
        this.pkey = pkey;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString () {
        return "Product{ " +
               "pkey=" + pkey +
               "| name='" + name +
               " }";
    }


    // -----------|  Accessors  |-----------------

    public Long getPkey () {
        return pkey;
    }

    public void setPkey ( Long pkey ) {
        this.pkey = pkey;
    }

    public String getName () {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName ( String name ) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Our `Order` class.

```
package com.basilbourque.example;

import java.time.Instant;

public class Order {
    Long pkey;  // Identifier of this order.
    Long fkeyProduct; // Identifier of the product being ordered.
    Instant whenOrdered; // The moment the order was placed.

    public Order ( Long pkey , Long fkeyProduct , Instant whenOrdered ) {
        this.pkey = pkey;
        this.fkeyProduct = fkeyProduct;
        this.whenOrdered = whenOrdered;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString () {
        return "Order{ " +
               "pkey=" + pkey +
               "| fkeyProduct=" + fkeyProduct +
               "| whenOrdered=" + whenOrdered +
               " }";
    }

    // -----------|  Accessors  |-----------------

    public Long getPkey () {
        return pkey;
    }

    public void setPkey ( Long pkey ) {
        this.pkey = pkey;
    }

    public Long getFkeyProduct () {
        return fkeyProduct;
    }

    public void setFkeyProduct ( Long fkeyProduct ) {
        this.fkeyProduct = fkeyProduct;
    }

    public Instant getWhenOrdered () {
        return whenOrdered;
    }

    public void setWhenOrdered ( Instant whenOrdered ) {
        this.whenOrdered = whenOrdered;
    }
}
```

### Maven POM

The `pom.xml` file, controlling [Maven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven) for loading dependencies (libraries) and for building/running the web app.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.basilbourque.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>prodpop</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>prodpop</name>

    <prerequisites>
        <maven>3</maven>
    </prerequisites>

    <properties>
        <vaadin.version>8.5.2</vaadin.version>
        <vaadin.plugin.version>8.5.2</vaadin.plugin.version>
        <jetty.plugin.version>9.4.12.v20180830</jetty.plugin.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>10</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>10</maven.compiler.target>
        <!-- If there are no local customizations, this can also be "fetch" or "cdn" -->
        <vaadin.widgetset.mode>local</vaadin.widgetset.mode>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>vaadin-addons</id>
            <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-push</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-client-compiled</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-themes</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--Basil-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.197</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <!-- Exclude an unnecessary file generated by the GWT compiler. -->
                    <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/classes/VAADIN/widgetsets/WEB-INF/**</packagingExcludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>update-theme</goal>
                            <goal>update-widgetset</goal>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <!-- Comment out compile-theme goal to use on-the-fly theme compilation -->
                            <goal>compile-theme</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <!-- Clean up also any pre-compiled themes -->
                <configuration>
                    <filesets>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>src/main/webapp/VAADIN/themes</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/styles.css</include>
                                <include>**/styles.scss.cache</include>
                            </includes>
                        </fileset>
                    </filesets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- The Jetty plugin allows us to easily test the development build by
                running jetty:run on the command line. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jetty.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>2</scanIntervalSeconds>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <!-- Vaadin pre-release repositories -->
            <id>vaadin-prerelease</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>

            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
                    <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases</url>
                </repository>
                <repository>
                    <id>vaadin-snapshots</id>
                    <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/vaadin-snapshots/</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
            <pluginRepositories>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
                    <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases</url>
                </pluginRepository>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>vaadin-snapshots</id>
                    <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/vaadin-snapshots/</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </pluginRepository>
            </pluginRepositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

---

By the way, in the macOS world, a “drop-down list” is known as a “pop-up menu” or a “popup”.